# Add popup window to TinyMCE buttons

Tags: tinymce, visual-editor, buttons

I'm looking for a good tutorial on how to create a popup window with a TinyMce button that would allow the user to select from multiple options, enter text into inputs, etc. I know how to create a button that displays a single prompt window, but that's about it and I've been searching for hours.

Anyone know some links?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a nice and a fairly new (a year old) tutorial that i've read a few days ago:

http://solislab.com/blog/how-to-make-shortcodes-user-friendly/

He has a great example and you can also download the source files and get a better understanding.