# TinyMCE popup windows using WP functions

Tags: shortcode, tinymce

In my editor I would like to use a TinyMCE generated popup to insert in the textarea some complex shortcodes. I use the TinyMCE API to show the popup (bottom of this question). The popup is a PHP file inside my theme. I would like:

1. To protect this file from external access (`if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) )` does not work).
2. Use some WP functions inside this popup.

Which is the way you could suggest?

*TinyMCE API call*

```
init : function(ed, url) {
        // Register the command so that it can be invoked by using tinyMCE.activeEditor.execCommand('mcecax_webnews');
        ed.addCommand('mcecax_webnews', function() {
                ed.windowManager.open({
                        file : url + '/dialog.php',
                        width : 650 + ed.getLang('cax_webnews.delta_width', 0),
                        height : 500 + ed.getLang('cax_webnews.delta_height', 0),
                        inline : 1
                }, {
                        plugin_url : url, // Plugin absolute URL
                        some_custom_arg : 'custom arg' // Custom argument
                });
        });
[...] CUTTED
```

Answer (score 1):

The popup of a TinyMCE is outside WordPress. You must include the `wp-load.php`, same handle like outside the WordPress install.

But think about this solution and maybe it is cleaner, that you create your data in a json string and handle this data in the popup. It is helpful to reads [this post](http://ottopress.com/2010/dont-include-wp-load-please/) about the include od wp-load.php.

Here you find a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/dnaber-de/1658122) with a example to write a TinyMCE popup dialog in WordPress, without to include the `wp-load.php`. The author have also write a [tutorial](http://dnaber.de/blog/2012/wordpress-tinymce-plugin-mit-dialogbox/), but only in German language.

Also the hint to this [WPSE Question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/12580/add-popup-window-to-tinymce-buttons) about a tutorial. This tutorial create the popup content only with javascript. Maybe more secure and the data for the handle will also communicate via js to the editor.