# pop-up options for custom quicktags

Tags: html-editor, quicktag

I always use HTML editor when writing an entry in my wordpress blog, I'm not sure why I can't bring myself to like the TinyMCE editor. After a while, I started to think about creating my own quicktags for HTML editor to make writing easier in the future.

thanks to [this article](http://codex.wordpress.org/Quicktags_API), I now (kinda) understand how to make my own quicktags. but after re-reading the article a couple of times, I still couldn't find a way to make a pop-up window like the one that the [default link quicktag has](http://inoel.org/images/quicktag-options.jpg).

Can anyone tell me how to make something like that? a way to make a pop-up options for quicktag, so that I could easily entered the arrays for my custom quicktags.

Thank You.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add popup window to TinyMCE buttons](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/12580/add-popup-window-to-tinymce-buttons)

Comment: Perhaps it's because I still don't have the necessary skill to accomplish what I want. But that link only gave me an example for custom button in TinyMCE, while what I want is an options window for HTML editor quicktag.